# Pandas mul with dense with sparse

Tags: python, pandas, sparse-matrix

I have a time-indexed `DataFrame` where only a subset of the data is valid (for some 'external' reason).

I have made a time-indexed `Series` of `1`s for valid data and `NaN`s where the data are invalid so I can use this as a mask on my `DataFrame`.

This `Series` is sparse.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rng = pd.date_range(start='2014-07-09', periods=5, freq='D')
data = np.random.randn(len(rng), 3)
col_names = ['spam', 'ham', 'eggs']    
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=rng, columns=col_names)    
valid_days = np.nan * np.ones_like(df.spam.values)
valid_days[2] =  1    
validity_mask = pd.SparseSeries(data=valid_days, index=rng)
```

I expected `df.mul(validity_mask, axis=0)` to give me 1 set of non-NaN `spam, ham, eggs`, instead, I got:

```
In [2]: df.mul(validity_mask, axis=0)
AssertionError: length mismatch: 5 vs. 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, of course,  that one needs to cast to `dense` before we multiply.

```
df.mul(validity_mask.to_dense(), axis=0)
```

gives the expected result of:

```
                spam       ham     eggs
2014-07-09       NaN       NaN      NaN
2014-07-10       NaN       NaN      NaN
2014-07-11  1.943166 -0.342399 -0.31517
2014-07-12       NaN       NaN      NaN
2014-07-13       NaN       NaN      NaN
```

I'm putting this here as I couldn't find anything about an explicit cast in the `Pandas` [binary operations docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#flexible-binary-operations) and [the Sparse data structure docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/sparse.html) simply say "Functionally, their behavior should be nearly identical to their dense counterparts."